# How do I require an image in Pug using Webpack

Tags: webpack, pug-loader, webpack-html-loader

I have the following config for my pug files...

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loaders: ["pug-html"]
}
```

This works great now I want to add an image that I load using url-loader. My structure is like this

```
src
  ...
    thing
      thing.template.pug
      thing.png
```

And I want to include the png so in the pug file I add...

img(src="thing.png")

This doesn't resolve so I tried things like `img(src=require("thing.png"))`. None of these work. I tried adding the html-loader like this...

```
 {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loaders: ["html?interpolate=require&-minimize", "pug-html"]
 },
```

but then I get...

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve directory './\"thing.png\"' in .../src/.../thing
 @ ./src/.../thing/thing.template.pug 1:128-164
```

This all works fine in my stylus with...

```
    {
      test: /.*[^\.global]\.styl$/,
      loaders: ["to-string", "css", "stylus"]
    },
```

I also tried...

```
img(src=statesmall.png)
```

and get `Cannot read property 'png' of undefined`

Also if I comment that line out with the html in there I see...

```
"Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div" ("module.exports = "<div><h1>Hey</h1><div class=\"terminal-output\">this thing</div>[ERROR ->]</div>";"): TerminalComponent@0:97"
```

How do I require an image in pug?

Answer (score 2):

This ended up working for me (although not really what I wanted)...

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loaders: ["apply", "pug"]
},

img(src=require("./thing.png"))
```

Of course I don't like wrapping in the require when I should be able to pipe to HTML loader but I can't get it to work.

Comment: hi Jackie, i am facing the same issue to get the image work in my pug template, i have the same webpack configuration and try to require the png by using require, it doesn't work and says require is undefined.. maybe im missing something could you please help on this as you fixed this?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't including the node types...

I would try adding these to your package.json...

```
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.30",
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a few months late, but I found an answer in the [html-loader documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#export-into-html-files) when I was just now having the same problem.

Basically, every time the loader finds a `img` tag it tries to resolve by default, but you can set the `attrs` query parameter to `false` to stop this behaviour. Of course, you'll now have to be mindful of img paths being relative to the build folder your rendered HTML is in and it won't rely on url-loader anymore.